# Parse JSON body from HTTP request (with ring and re-frame-http-fx)

Tags: clojure, ring, re-frame

I have a re-frame-based UI and try to communicate with my server using [re-frame-http-fx](https://github.com/Day8/re-frame-http-fx). Sending and responding seems to work. However, I can't figure out how to parse the JSON body into a Clojure map on the server.

Here is my `handler.clj` as minimal as I could get it:

```
(ns my.handler
  (:require [compojure.core :refer [GET POST defroutes]]
            [compojure.route :refer [resources]]
            [ring.util.response :refer [resource-response]]
            [ring.middleware.json :refer [wrap-json-response wrap-json-body]]))

(defn json-post [request]
  (let [body (:body request)]
    (prn body)
    body))

(defroutes routes
  (GET       "/"     []      (resource-response "index.html" {:root "public"}))
  (POST      "/post" request json-post)
  (resources "/"))

(def handler (wrap-json-response (wrap-json-body routes {:keywords? true})))
```

As far as I understand, the `wrap-json-body` middleware should replace the request body by a parsed version (a map?).

However, the output I get from `(prn body)` in my `json-post` handler is something like this:
`#object[org.httpkit.BytesInputStream 0xda8b162 "BytesInputStream[len=41]"]`

If I try something like `(prn (:title body))` I get `nil` (although the original map-turned-json-request contains `:title`, as well as both the request and response body).

The request and response contain the correct json. The request `Content-Type` is correctly set to `application/json` (sent by `re-frame-http-fx`). The length of the buffer (41) is also the correct body length as per request.

I am running out of things to try. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you try slurping the input stream to see what is in it? And can you try without wrapping the JSON response?

Comment: Slurping the input stream gives me the raw request body that contains the expected json. I did not try to remove the ring middleware, because I stumbled upon the solution (see answer). Thanks and sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While investigating the issue further, I found my error that lead to the effect. It concerns the `dev-handler` from the re-frame template that I conventiently omitted from my minimal example in the question.

I did not realize it was a problem, because the application seems to start fine even if you delete the entire definition of `dev-handler` from `handler.clj`, I assume because the server is initialized with `handler` in `server.clj` anyway (and the client does not fail fatally).

However, in `project.clj` of the re-frame template, the following is configured for figwheel:

```
  :figwheel {:css-dirs ["resources/public/css"]
             :ring-handler my.handler/dev-handler}
```

This leads to middleware configured for `handler` not being applied to my requests, thus not unwrapping the json body. Changing either the definition of `dev-handler` (the the same as `handler` in the question) or the configuration of figwheel in `project.clj` (to point to `handler` instead of `dev-handler`) solves the problem.

If anybody knows the reasoning of different handlers in `project.clj` and `server.clj`, feel free to let me know.